# Assertion failed error: in ember when api is called after transition to another page

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

We call an API from login page, and then transition to page called 2fa. On transition we call an api which send 2fa code after sucessfull login. and then redirect to 2fa page.

on login action

```
         is2FASave.save().then((response) => {
            if(response.data.is2fa){
                this.get('session').setLoginCredential(email,password);
                var sendCode = this.store.createRecord('sendCode', {
                    email: email,
                    password: password
                });
                sendCode.save().then((res) => {
                    this.get('store').unloadAll('sendCode');
                    this.transitionToRoute('twofa')
                },(error)=>{
                });
            }
         }
```

On twofa page we have resend button on its click where we call same api 
which is written on twofa controller

actions: {

```
    /**
     * Resend 2FA code.
     */
    twoFaResend: function() {
        var email = this.get('session').getEmail(),
            password = this.get('session').getPassword();
        var sendCode = this.store.createRecord('sendCode', {
            email: email,
            password: password
        });
        sendCode.save().then((res) => {
        },(error)=>{
        });
    },
```

while we call this api on twofa page it gives error

> Assertion Failed: You can only unload a record which is not inFlight.
>   `<send-code:null>`"

The error is shown as after the resend code button is clicked 
[image]

When we check ember data it has value of previous api call. 
[image]

Now we also tried calling the same api multiple times on same page which works absolutely fine. Dis issue occurs when it is transitioned to other page and api is called on another page.

Comment: Recent versions of ember-data have issues with unloading records and then re-adding them. Probably you ran in such issue. Try [this](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/reusing-ids-for-soft-deleted-records/13715/6) to unload record. I use this [function](https://gist.github.com/GendelfLugansk/4ab727a916c38d13cf9d02dae35eb163) to unload records and call it after deleting record from store.

Comment: Is there any reason, you are unloading all records but not only the one created? In general what your are doing does not really fit into `ember-data`. ember-data is meant to handle records not to fire actions. `sendCode` seems to be more an action than a model having many records. Is there any reason not to do a simple ajax call to fire the action?